# ejabberd - Running escript from the same context as `ejabberdctl debug`

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

Part of setting up my ejabberd server includes running `ejabberdctl debug` and entering some commands. Instead, I would like to have a file that is executed, but have it run from the same context of the `ejabberdctl debug` REPL. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the rpc:call command. The Node value is what you see at the debug prompt "name@host".

Also, make sure the escript sets the appropriate cookie value.

Let me clarify, if the debug environment looked like this:

```
(ejabberd@host)1>
```

You can create a escript file which looks like this. This updates the log level:

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript

%%! -sname script1 -setcookie cookie -hidden
main([Level]) ->
   rpc:call('ejabberd@host', ejabberd_loglevel, set, [list_to_atom(Level)]).
```